# How can I compress the Outlook 2010 mailbox?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have Microsoft Outlook 2010 installed on my local PC.  My PC cannot download Windows updates because there is not enough space.  Therefore I have cleared out my email inbox, calendar etc.  My mailbox is completely empty.

I checked the .ost file before and after (I double checked I got the correct location); the file has not changed in size i.e. it is still 20GB.

How can I compress the mailbox? I have looked at File/Mailbox Options and it says: 14.7GB free of 14.8GB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the mailbox is mostly empty space, you may compact it this way:

- In Outlook, File tab, select "Account Settings" and then click "Account Settings"
- Click the Data Files tab
- Select the file to compact and click Settings
- In the Data File dialogue box, click Compact Now.

Comment: I already tried that.  There is no option to compact .ost files.  There is an option to compact .pst files.

Comment: You can delete the OST file and remake it it by running Outlook Synchronization again.

Comment: @John, do you mean delete the mailbox and create from scratch?

Comment: If there is only an OST file for the mailbox (that is, no PST file with it), then yes, delete the mailbox, Outlook Account, restart Outlook and set it up again.

Comment: You might find the Compact button in the Advanced tab. See [link](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/compact-now-pst-and-ost).